# Как поместить проект в Docker container, указать зависимости от других контейнеров, обращаться к сервису другого контейнера?

Tags: .net, asp.net, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Есть мой ASP.NET 8 проект (сервер), мое .net 8 консольное приложение (клиент), образ minio (или какой-либо другой образ с docker hub).
Нужно, чтобы клиент мог достучаться до сервера, который в докер контейнере, из докера и из хоста. Сервер должен общаться с minio, который тоже в докер контейнере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вещи, которые я долго гуглил или выпрашивал у уже "смешариков".

**Dockerfile** - файл со "скриптом", описывает по шагам, как билдить контейнер (аналог `.sh` скрипта, `.bat`, `cmakelists.txt`). Создается в папке проекта. Создал его `Rider`'ом (руками не писал), нормально работает. Мне понадобилось трогать там только `EXPOSE` - указывает порт, который будет открытым (оставил только `EXPOSE 7666`).

Пример (ASP.NET 8 проект):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER $APP_UID
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 7666

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyServer/MyServer.csproj", "MyServer/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyServer/MyServer.csproj"

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyServer"
RUN dotnet build "MyServer.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "MyServer.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyServer.dll"]
```

**docker-compose.yaml** - он нужен для конфигурации запуска контейнера(-ов). Создается в папке решения. Он сам запустит `Dockerfile`, если нужные контейнеры еще не собраны.

В `Rider` можно выполнить весь `docker-compose.yaml` (кнопка пуска около `services`), либо только какой-то конкретный сервис (запустить контейнер) (кнопка пуска около контейнера).

`docker-compose.yaml` можно выполнить из консоли, выполнив `docker compose up` в консоли в директории с этим файлом.

Как я понял, запускать контейнер в первый раз из интерфейса *Docker Desktop* (функционал ограничен) или запускать его из консоли без `docker-compose.yaml` (много букав писать) - кринж; ну и всё равно нужна автоматизация запуска и конфигурации.

В коде оставил комментарии, всё должно стать понятно.

```
#docker-compose.yaml

services: #далее перечисление контейнеров
  minio: #как назовем контейнер
    image: minio/minio:latest #docker image from docker hub
                              #(вроде должно само скачаться, если не скачано)
                              #вместо latest в проде следует использовать
                              #конкретную версию, на которой было протестировано,
                              #а то он упадет когда-нибудь.

    command: server --console-address ":9001" /data/

    ports: #проброс портов.
      - "9050:9070" #с хоста можно отправить запрос в http(s)://localhost:9050,
                    #он придет в 9070 порт внутри контейнера (если EXPOSEd)
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"

    environment: #переменные среды)
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: aaa111
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: bbb222333
    volumes: #внизу файла обьявление томов, тут использование
      - minio-storage:/data #монтирует minio-storage как директорию /data

  myserver: #название контейнера, в котором будет мой сервер
    image: myserver #название образа (не с докер хаба, а локальное.
                    #появится в докере либо после запуска этого файла,
                    #либо докерфайла отдельно)

    ports:
      - "7777:7666"
    build:
      context: . #не знаю, что это. работает, не трогаю.
      dockerfile: MyServer/Dockerfile #путь к докер файлу проекта
                                      #относительно этого docker-compose.yaml,
                                      #Он будет выполнен при выполнении этого файла,
                                      #если сурскод потерял актуальность (не точно)
                                      #или image еще не создан
    depends_on: [minio] #перед запуском этого контейнера (myserver) сначала
                        #скачается/настроится/запустится контейнер minio
    volumes:
      - myserver-storage:/data
    environment:
#
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: "http://+:7666" #в ASP.NET 8 это позволяет задать порт 7666
                                       #как прослушиваемый, вместо дефолтного 8080.
                                       #если вместо http написать https, будет https (не факт, лучше загуглить)
                         #как я понял, launchSettings.json не актуален для докера

  client: #мой "клиент"
    image: client
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Client/Dockerfile
    depends_on: [ myserver ] #перед запуском client должен быть запущен myserver
    environment:
      WEBAPI_URL: http://myserver:7666 #контейнер может стучаться в другой контейнер,
                                       #используя название контейнера
    volumes:
      - trash-storage:/data

volumes: #тома в докере. существуют независимо от контейнеров.
  minio-storage: #после двоеточия ничего можно не писать.
                 #будет создан том {название решения (.net)}_minio-storage
  myserver-storage:
```

Если в `MyServer/Dockerfile` не написать `EXPOSE 7666`, то из другого контейнера нельзя будет достучаться в этот по порту 7666, хост тоже не достучится по порту 7777. если написать `EXPOSE 7666`, но не написать `ports: - "7777:7666"`, то из других контейнеров все равно можно достучаться в этого контейнер по 7666 порту .

Еще по этой теме:

- [питон](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/)
- [microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0](https://habr.com/ru/companies/microsoft/articles/435914/)
- [HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-8.0)
- [питон, более детально расписано местами](https://habr.com/ru/companies/ruvds/articles/450312/)
- [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).